# javascript to show/hide SVG elements when you click other SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg

I am making an interactive map and want to show hide different SVG elements when others are clicked. [I started with this}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484743/show-and-hide-elements-inside-svgs) but I don't want all the 'g' elements to hide, only specific ones. I tried changing the getelement tag to id but it didn't seem to work.

updated: got it to target classes and updated my code info. The one textbox I want to stay open is not. I hope I made things more clear, thank you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <![CDATA[
        var id = 'name';
        
    function place(id) {
      var gs =  document.getElementsByClassName("textboxes");
    
      // Hide all the elements    
      for (var i = 0; i < gs.length; i++) {
        gs[i].classList.add("hidden");
      }
      // But make sure the one with "id" is visible
      document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("hidden");
    }
        ]]>
        </script>
```

my map item with the onclick:

```
    <g onclick="place('accelerator')" id="accelerator-n">
                <a  xlink:href="#">
                    <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="539.1322" y1="175.0099" x2="543.4789" y2="175.0099">
                    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A7A9AC"/>
                    <stop  offset="2.965399e-02" style="stop-color:#ACAEB1"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.1582" style="stop-color:#BCBEC0"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.3016" style="stop-color:#C6C7C9"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.4888" style="stop-color:#C9CACC"/>
                    <stop  offset="0.8212" style="stop-color:#CCCDCF"/>
                    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D1D3D4"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <polygon class="st4" points="544.2,340.9 542.9,341.8 542.8,160.8 544.3,159.3            "/>
                <polygon class="st6" points="542.4,175.6 539.1,175.3 540.2,174.4 543.5,174.4            "/>
                <polygon class="st5" points="539.3,341.9 543,341.9 543,160.6 538.7,160.5            "/>
                </a>
                </g>
```

two textboxes, the introinfo box should be seen on loading and others hide/show depending on what map element you click on:

```
    <g id="introinfo" class="textboxes">
        <rect x="28.8" y="33.8" class="st32" width="345.7" height="251.7"/>
        <foreignobject  x="34" y="40" width="338" height="238">
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >Here is a long text that runs more than one line and works as a paragraph</div>
                    <br />
                    <div>This is <u>UNDER LINE</u> one</div>
                    <br />
                    <div>This is <b>BOLD</b> one</div>
                    <br />
                    <div>This is <i>Italic</i> one</div>
            </foreignobject>
    </g>
        
        
        <g id="accelerator" class="textboxes">
        <rect fill="red" x="28.8" y="33.8" class="st32a" width="345.7" height="251.7"/>
        <foreignobject  x="34" y="40" width="338" height="238">
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >accelerator BOX of text.</div>
                    <br />
                    <div>This is <u>accelerator BOX of text.</u> one</div>
                    <br />
                    <div>This is <b>accelerator BOX of text.</b> one</div>
                    <br />
                    <div>This is <i>accelerator BOX of text.</i> one</div>
            </foreignobject>
    </g>
```

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be using a toggle: `gs.classList.toggle("visible");`

Comment: I tried to apply your change but I don't believe I I did it correctly, can you explain or link me to more info please. The use and coding of SVG is new to me and I am trying to shoe string this together. Thank you for helping as well.

Answer (score 2):

As per @enxaneta's suggestion, using classes is a little cleaner.

However, you might prefer to use a "hidden" class rather than one named "visible".  Depending on whether your elements are normally visible or hidden.  Your choice.

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

Then your code would become

```
var id = 'name';

function place(id) {
  var gs = document.getElementsByTagName("g");

  // Hide all the elements    
  for (var i = 0; i < gs.length; i++) {
    gs[i].classList.add("hidden");
  }
  // But make sure the one with "id" is visible
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

**Working demo**

```js
function place(id) {
  var gs = document.getElementsByTagName("g");

  // Hide all the elements    
  for (var i = 0; i < gs.length; i++) {
    gs[i].classList.add("hidden");
  }
  // But make sure the one with "id" is visible
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("hidden");
}


function reset() {
  document.querySelectorAll("g").forEach(g => g.classList.remove("hidden"));
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="100">
  <g id="one" onclick="place('one')">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red"/>
  </g>
  <g id="two" onclick="place('two')">
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="40" fill="orange"/>
  </g>
  <g id="three" onclick="place('three')">
    <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="40" fill="gold"/>
  </g>
  <g id="four" onclick="place('four')">
    <circle cx="350" cy="50" r="40" fill="green"/>
  </g>
</svg>


<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset circles</button>
```

Comment: Hmmm.. that just hid everything on click. How can I selectively turn groups on and off when clicked?

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong.  I've added a demo to show the `place()` code works fine.

Comment: I got it to target classes so only the textboxes hide but the one I want to stay showing is not. I updated my code above and your code did work when I put it in but it too also hid all the group elements which included my map.

Comment: I also tried to change the script to target the proper textbox to stay showing but nothing I did worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Your `id` names don't match: `accelerator` vs `accelerator-n`.

Comment: YAY!!!  OK, much better. I implemented the working code into my map and all proper textboxes are showing when the corresponding map item is clicked on!!! I also cleaned up my classes and ID's so they make more sense - I have one issue I've run into. They all show on load, can all but the "introinfo" textbox be hidden on load? So the "introinfo" shows first then hides as you click on each map item? I can't thank yo enough for your help with this. I tried to style in them being hidden, I even tried to place onload the introinfo - neither worked.

Comment: update: I put the onload to place the introinfo in the top level SVG tag and it's working!!!  Is this correct? I don't think it'll have a negative effect?

Comment: That should be fine.

Comment: last ting I promise!! I used a refresh script as a reset button like you had but it's clunky when refreshing the browser. I've been trying to modify the reset script you used to hide all the but the introinfo box by combining some of the commands from the show/hide script but haven't had success.

Comment: I'm going to try and make an SVG element and apply the place introinfo on click  like the others, this should work.

Comment: it worked, all textboxes can be accessed and the a button to reset to the introinfo - thank you again for you help.